# Number of paths of length n+i in n x n grid with diagonal

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

given the directed grid below of size $n \times n$, I would like to obtain the number of path possible of length $n + i$, $i = 0, \ldots, n$.

[Example of grid of size 4 x 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1L6h.png)

You move from bottom left (start) to top right (finish). The steps you are allowed to do are going up, going right, or going diagonally. 
In class, we saw that the total number of path in such a graph is given by the following : $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n+i \choose n}\cdot {n \choose i}$.

My intuition was to say that for each $i$, the number of path of length $i$ is defined by ${n+i \choose n} {n \choose i}$. I did the calculation for grids of size 1,2,3,4 by hand, and it seems to work. Afterwards, the computation is too long to do by hand.

My question is the following, does it make sense? And if yes, could you explain to me why it works, e.g. how does it mean in this case to choose ${n+i \choose n}{n \choose i}$ paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r, u, d$ be the number of moves to the right, up, and diagonally, respectively.

Then we have that $r+u+d=n+i,\;\;r+d=n,\;\;$ and $u+d=n$,

(since a diagonal move results in a move to the right and up at the same time),

$\;\;\;\;$so $u=r=i\;\;$ and $d=n-i$.

The number of ways to arrange $i$ u's, $i$ r's, and $n-i$ d's in order is given by

$\hspace{.4 in}\dbinom{n+i}{i}\dbinom{n}{i}=\dbinom{n+i}{n}\dbinom{n}{i}$,

since there are $\binom{n+i}{i}$ ways to place the u's and then $\binom{n}{i}$ ways to place the r's.